# Lucene: BestTextFragments returns only the first document

Tags: java, search, twitter, indexing, lucene

I'm building a Lucene index for Twitter User with their Tweets. My idea is to store info about User (name, description, ecc) with his tweets with the following code:

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, User> entry : users.entrySet()) {

        User user = entry.getValue();

        Document document = new Document();

        document.add(new LongField("id", user.getId(), Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new StringField("name", user.getName(), Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new StringField("username", user.getUsername(), Field.Store.YES));

        for (UserTweet t : user.getTweets()) {
            document.add(new TextField("tweet", t.getText(), Field.Store.YES));
        }

        writer.addDocument(document);
    }
```

Here a document can have a lot of tweets in the "tweet" field. *The analyzer used for this field is the EnglishAnalyzer.*

**Is this method correct to store tweets?**

My problem is when I set the Highlighter to retrieve the tweets that match. If I search a term that is present in ALL tweets of ALL stored users, as a result I get ALL users (correct!), but **if I want to see all Tweets of a single user that match with the query (with Highlighter) I get only the first Tweet of every user and not all.**

This is the code that I use to search:

```
BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

QueryParser queryParserKeywords = new QueryParser("tweet", new EnglishAnalyzer());

String strQueryKeywords = "";
for (String s : c.getValue().split(" ")) 
     strQueryKeywords += "tweet:"+ s +" OR ";
strQueryKeywords = strQueryKeywords.substring(0, strQueryKeywords.lastIndexOf("OR"));

Query queryKeywords = queryParserKeywords.parse(strQueryKeywords);

QueryScorer queryScorerKeywords = new QueryScorer(queryKeywords, "tweet");
Fragmenter fragment = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(queryScorerKeywords, 150);

keywordsHighlighter = new Highlighter(queryScorerKeywords);
keywordsHighlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragment);

booleanQuery.add(queryKeywords, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

... (other boolean clause over other fields)

searcher.search(booleanQuery.build(), collector);

...

for (ScoreDoc doc : collector.topDocs().scoreDocs) {
    Document d = searcher.doc(doc.doc);
    TokenStream tokenStream = new EnglishAnalyzer().tokenStream("",d.getField("tweet").stringValue());
    TextFragment[] fragments = keywordsHighlighter.getBestTextFragments(tokenStream, d.getField("tweet").stringValue(), false, 10);
    for (TextFragment fragment : fragments) {
        System.out.println(" - " + fragment.toString());
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

At last, to search over multiple fields with different text (ex: City=New York, Keyword=Star Wars, ecc.), Is it correct to use the BooleanQuery or exist a better solution?

Thanks a lot.